# Maven exec plugin multiple executions not working

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying to make the Maven exec plugin run multiple executions when I invoke the `exec:java` goal in the following way:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>first</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example.First</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>second</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.example.Second</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However upon running `mvn exec:java` with maven 3.1.1 I get the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project test: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
```

Running the `exec:java` goal for a single execution (without using the nested `executions` element) works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the problem is that neither of the `<execution/>` is tied to a particular `<phase/>`. Try setting one.

Comment: If I execute the plug-in explicitly with "exec:java" which phase should that be?

Comment: Well, if the `mainClass` that you're specifying is part of the module's source, you'll need to have compiled the code first, so the bare minimum would be `compile`, although I would recommend `package` which also runs the tests. For detailed list of the possible phases, check here: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html and here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html. Perhaps the problem is that at the time you want to run the exec goal, the classes are not yet compiled...?

Comment: Also I've noticed that maven-exec-plugin does not support multiple excutions for the `java` goal. More information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562558/the-maven-exec-plugin-executes-only-first-execution