# The maven-exec-plugin executes only first execution

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I need to execute several java classes during maven build phase, but plugin executes only class from first execution

Pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>first</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.myPackage.AssignTest</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>second</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.myPackage.CompareTest</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Does somebody know where is an error?

Comment: just to be sure: you're calling `mvn test-compile` and this block is *not* within pluginManagement.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone will want an answer to this. 
From experimenting I've found that the `java` goal does not support multiple executions, but the `exec` goal does. So just *transform java into exec*

Below is an example of how to run the above code with the `exec` goal.

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution-one</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-cp</argument>
                            <classpath/>
                            <argument>com.myPackage.AssignTest</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution-two</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <arguments>
                             <argument>-cp</argument>
                             <classpath/>
                             <argument>com.myPackage.CompareTest</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

If classes you want to run reside in your actual code, you will probably need to bind the exec goal to a phase after `compile`. Else they will simply be picked up from the project dependencies.